# plugins update error "Some plugins require plugin JNA to be installed netbeans"

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-plugins, netbeans-12

i am trying to install a plugin [embedded-browser](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/38508/embedded-browser), but it's showing me error, i am using netbeans version 12.0 on arch linux.

```
Some plugins require plugin JNA to be installed.
The plugin JNA is requested in version >= 1.3 (release version 1) but only 2.3 (of release version different from 1) was found.  

The following plugin is affected:       
               Embedded Browser UI - XUL Runner
```

i ahev searched on the plugin portal but there is no plugin for `jna` i am also getting the same error when updating plugins..but with just diffrent plugin affected..

```
Some plugins require plugin JNA to be installed.
The plugin JNA is requested in version >= 1.11 (release version 1) but only 2.3 (of release version different from 1) was found.  
The following plugin is affected:       
              Subversion SvnKit Client Library
```

Answer (score 3):

Refer to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-4704 "I solved the problem by unchecking the NetBeans 8.2 Plugin Portal."

This worked for me too.